# SQLi Code not inserting into Correct Row with Using User ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I Have been trying to Fix this code and It Never works No matter what I do with it. It should Insert into the Database You have found a secret Game Into The logged in user's Row using the user ID that is stored in the session is there a way to fix this code as I'm Stumped.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (code, link)
VALUES ('You Found a Secret Game!', '/12283719823838hdhj/') WHERE id = " . 
$_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Yakshemash. Any error messages ? What do you expect and what actually happens ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Hi, It doesn't Return any error Messages. It should Insert into the database You have found a secret game The second they click on the page into their row in the database using their User ID in the session   but instead it doesn't insert anything to the database

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any WHERE with an INSERT INTO.

Try this:

[EDIT]
Ok then try this.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   echo "MySQL Error: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
unset($query);
$query  = "UPDATE login SET code = 'You Found a Secret Game!', link = '/12283719823838hdhj/' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'";
var_dump($query);
if (!$mysqli->query($query) {
    echo "Mysql Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok I have tried both but the first one won't insert as it has no values and the second wont insert into the correct row

Comment: It Doesn't Give back anything

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (code, link)
                   VALUES ('You Found a Secret Game!', '/12283719823838hdhj/') 
                 WHERE id ='".$_SESSION['user']['id']."' ",ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

Comment: ok then use your variable , because i was just doubt if its right your variable.look edited